# Is there a SortedMultimap type implementation in Guava that doesn't care about the order of its values

Tags: java, guava

E.g. I want a multimap from Integer to zero or more File objects. I'd like the map to stay sorted as I insert or remove entries. But I don't care about the order of the values (Files), which don't have a natural ordering anyway.

There doesn't seem to be an implementation that I can see (which is really unfortunate), so right now I'm stuck using `TreeMap<Integer, List<File>>`.

Answer (score 4):

[`MultimapBuilder`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MultimapBuilder.html) should be able to do what you want:

```
SetMultimap<Integer, File> multimap =
    MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().hashSetValues().build();
```

Comment: Thanks. Apparently MultimapBuilder wasn't in guava 15.0 (which is what  our private API currently depends on), so before I upgrade it I need to make sure nothing depends on the various deprecated stuff that got removed between 15 and 16.

Comment: Now that I've had a change to test this - this isn't what I'm after as a SetMultimap doesn't have an ordering on its keys. I think some of the confusion stems from the fact that a SortedMap in the java API provides an ordering on its keys, but there is no equivalent SortedMultimap interface in guava that also provides an order on its keys.

Comment: There's not an _interface_, but the provided implementation does keep an order on its keys anyway.